# Are the orders of these group elements relatively prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are elements of finite order in a group such that $ab=ba$ and $ \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = \{e\}$.

Is this true or false: 'the orders of $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime'.

Help, please...

Comment: the condition on <a>\cap <b> is missing.

Comment: what do you mean? :)

$ \langle a \rangle $ mean subgroup generated by a

Comment: what do you mean by "ab=ba and <a>\cap <b>"? I understand what ab=ba means but what else are you trying to say?

Comment: ahh..., sorry...
it's not complete...
$ \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle = e $

it's what I mean...

Comment: please edit your post then (and you mean <a>\cap <b>={e})

Comment: thanks... :)

can you help how to solve this problem?

Comment: The group generated by $a,b$, which have those properties as well as $(|a|,|b|)=1$ is necessarily cyclic, so any (noncyclic) elementary abelian group serves as a counterexample.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the Klein Group: $$V=\{e,a,b,c\}$$ where in $$a^2=b^2=c^2=1$$ and $$ab=ba=c,bc=cb=a,ca=ac=b$$ We have $|a|=|b|=|c|=2$ and we can see that $$\langle a\rangle=\{e,a\}\\ \langle b\rangle=\{e,b\}\\ \langle c\rangle=\{e,c\}$$ Now, check if your claim is true or not.

Comment: so.., it's false, right?

Comment: @chihiroasleaf: Yes. ;-)

Comment: ok.., thank you... :)

Comment: @chihiroasleaf: I did nothing for you. I hope I could help you. Welcome. :-)

Comment: This example generalises. If $G$ is the direct product of the cyclic groups $A=\langle a\rangle$ and $B=\langle b\rangle$, $G=A\times B$, then $ab=ba$ and $A\cap B=1$. In the example here, $A$ and $B$ are both cyclic of order two.

Comment: Great example! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Nice to see you after you go sleep.

Comment: @Babak: I'll go to sleep within the hour; so I'll look forward to seeing you until then, and maybe when I wake up, say, 9 hours from now!

Comment: @amWhy: Sleep in peace! Have a graphical dream! :D